Campaign graph is not showing the chart
We migrated the xDB data from 9.1 to 10.3 sitecore so everything works fine as in SS below

but, only Campaign data is not showing. We tried to rebuild the secondary reporting db also but it didn't help.
In the network console, the following API
https://sc103uat-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/v2/2B6EF914175F4DC1BE6F05255B437A91/all/all?&dateGrouping=collapsed&site=all&&dateFrom=11-04-2023&dateTo=11-04-2024&keyGrouping=by-key&keyTop=50

returns the data as

So, not sure where to start to check why totalRecordCount is zero, because I think if this returns some count then in the chart there will be some patterns be visible.

did you deploy the campaign ?

In the past, I have seen this situation, when the Campaigns of its taxonomy was not deployed.
Please check and confirm that the taxonomies - like campaign channel and campaign facet, etc., related to your campaign are deployed.

Sitecore uses reference database to store marketing taxonomies such as campaigns, goals and outcomes. You can clear the reference tables and redeploy the marketing definitions from the control panel.

Data stored on the reference database(xDB Reference Data) is then used for aggregation purposes. You can find the data flow here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/collecting-experience-data.html
Hope this helps.
